# Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'int *' from 'int' and segmentation fault error (Array and Lenght as pointers)

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Im trying to create a array as a pointer using a function, and assigning random integers to that array.

But inside the for loop i am getting the following warning message, on equals sign:

```
Warning Here ↓↓↓ - Incompatible integer to pointer conversion.
 array[index] = rand() % 100;
```

> incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'int *' from
> 'int'

And when i execute, i get the following error:

> signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)

Below is my code, with lots of comments to specify what is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // Lib for rand() to work

// Function: Create array and its lenght, save to a pointer.
int createArray(
    int **array,
    size_t *size) { // Initiate pointers of array and array size
  printf("What will be the size of the array?: ");
  scanf("%ld", &*size); // For formatting using "size_t" we use %ld

  for (int index = 0; index != *size; index++) {

    /*
     * Warning Message on Equals Sign below: incompatible integer to pointer
     * conversion assigning to 'int *' from 'int' */

    array[index] = rand() % 100; // Equal sign is giving me a warning. (??)
  }
  printf("\n --- Array created. Pointers: *size, *array --- \n");
  return 0;
}

// Function: Print elements of pointer array specifying its size from pointer.
void *arrayElements(int array[], size_t size) {
  printf("\n --- Printing Elements of array --- \n");
  // Loop through the array by incrementing value of i
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  int *array; // Instance pointer (Persistent variable -- For remembering what it does)
  size_t size;
  createArray(&array, &size);
  arrayElements(array, size);

  return 0;
}
```

If i change **array[index]** = rand() % 100; to ***array[index]** = rand() % 100;, the warning goes away but i get **illegal instruction** error when executing.

What i want to achieve:
Pass a array and its size as pointers using a function, then print its elements from another function using those pointers.

Please, can someone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Well `array` is a pointer to a pointer to int. So when you dereference once, you get a pointer to int.

Comment: Despite that, you haven't allocated any memory for `array`.

Comment: `scanf("%ld", &*size);` is the same as `scanf("%ld", size);`. The correct format specifier for `size_t` is `"%zu"`

Comment: How can i allocate a memory for array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things wrong,

1. `scanf("%ld", &*size)`, the two operators `&*` cancel each other, so `&*size` is just redundant. `scanf("%ld", size)` is enough. (If you are allowed to use, the standard format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`).
2. You also need to check the return value of `scanf` since you are using the variable to allocate space for your array, it's crucial that the conversion succeeded.
3. You never allocate memory for `array`.
4. You are trying to store an `int` to an `int *` variable.

Since `array` is of type `int **` a single dereference `array[index]` yields a pointer to int

`array[index] --> *(array + index)`

`*array[index]` won't work either because of operator precedence

*([] operator will be evaluated first and the result will be dereferenced)*

What you want is `(*array)[index] = rand() % 100;`

or `array[0][index] = rand() % 100;`

or even `*(*array + index) = rand() % 100;`

```
int createArray(
    int **array,
    size_t *size)
{ 
// first make sure you didn't get NULL pointers
if (array == NULL || size == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "createArray: null pointer\n");
    return 1;
}
// Initiate pointers of array and array size
    printf("What will be the size of the array?: ");
    if (scanf("%zu", size) != 1) { // conversion failed
        fprintf(stderr, "scanf: error reading size\n");
        return 1; 
    }

    *array = malloc(*size * sizeof(int)); // dereference array pointer and allocate memory
    // alternatively, you can use array[0] = ... which is the same

    if (*array == NULL) { // allocation failed
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc: error allocating memory for array\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (size_t index = 0; index < *size; index++) // use size_t since size is size_t
    {
        // dereference first and assign value to array[index]
        (*array)[index] = rand() % 100;
    }
    printf("\n --- Array created. Pointers: *size, *array --- \n");
    return 0;
}
```

I also noticed that `void *arrayElements(int array[], size_t size)` returns a void pointer. Since you don't actually return anything,

`void arrayElements(int array[], size_t size)` should be enough.

Comment: Nice. I still dont understand this fully tho. Why does malloc(*size * sizeof(int)); works ? What is it doing ?

Comment: @RaulChiarella The whole operation reserves space for `size` number of integers. `sizeof(int)` yields the size of a integer in bytes, if you multiply that by `size`, you will get the desired amount of integers in bytes, which is reserved and a pointer is returned.